# Repository release doesn't exist anymore

Tags: updates

I am being outputted the following code every time I try to sudo apt-get update:

```
Err:1 http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt Mirrorlist
      Could not connect to mirrors.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.89.32), connection timed out
    Ign:2 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal InRelease
    Ign:3 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates InRelease
    Err:4 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal Release
      Downloading mirror file failed
    Err:5 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates Release
      Downloading mirror file failed
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: The repository 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal Release' no longer has a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    E: The repository 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried configuring the files in the /etc/apt/sources.list by changing it to archives.ubuntu, but it still didn't work. Can anyone help out. This is my sys release:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Elementary
Description:    elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir
Release:    6.1
Codename:   jolnir
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your /etc/apt/sources.list. Replacing all 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt' urls with 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' urls.

Should look like that:

```
deb cdrom:[elementary OS 6.1 _odin_ - stable amd64 (20211218)]/ focal contrib main non-free
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

Comment: Any change you could include why this happened?

Comment: I can't tell. Used the url also in my config until the day before yesterday. But I had this issue also earlier. Maybe the mirror is not synced propperly or unsupported. 

But you can use https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors to check archive links and their versions.